# How to convert string into float in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, floating-point

I am trying to parse two values from a datagrid. The fields are numeric, and when they have a comma (ex. 554,20), I can't get the numbers after the comma. I've tried `parseInt` and `parseFloat`. How can I do this?

Comment: **see also:**  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318654

Answer (score 437, accepted):

If they're meant to be separate values, try this:

```
var values = "554,20".split(",")
var v1 = parseFloat(values[0])
var v2 = parseFloat(values[1])
```

If they're meant to be a single value (like in French, where one-half is written 0,5)

```
var value = parseFloat("554,20".replace(",", "."));
```

Comment: What about where you have a comma used as a thousand seperator? 
E.g. 1234 written as 1,234

Comment: You could just remove the comma, then parse it. (eg. replace it with "")

Comment: it's not very safe, as sconto = parseFloat("5,,5".replace(",", ".")); returns 5 leading one to believe it's a valid number, but you loose the .5 part or you could consider it is not a valid number

Comment: @max4ever If you're worried about silently accepting invalid numbers, you can use ```+(string)``` instead of ```parseString(string)``` as suggested by @Stev below. So, the first example would be ```v1 = +(values[0]); v2 = +(values[1]);```.

Comment: FAIL, what if my number is `6.000.000`. Function replace only replace first comma separator

Comment: Use a regex as the first param with the `g` flag in order to do a global replace on the string. e.g. `string.replace(/,/g, '.')`.

Comment: I hate the manual hack of replacing `,` with `.`. Couldn't `parseFloat` take a *locale* parameter instead?

Answer (score 64):

Have you ever tried to do this? :p

```
var str = '3.8';ie
alert( +(str) + 0.2 );
```

+(string) will cast string into float.

Handy!

So in order to solve your problem, you can do something like this:

```
var floatValue = +(str.replace(/,/,'.'));
```

Comment: I really like the `+(str)` solution - `parseFloat` ignores invalid characters after the number, `+(str)` returns `NaN` in those cases, which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 47):

Replace the comma with a dot.

This will only return 554:

```
var value = parseFloat("554,20")
```

This will return 554.20:

```
var value = parseFloat("554.20")
```

So in the end, you can simply use:

```
var fValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("textfield").value.replace(",","."))
```

Don't forget that `parseInt()` should only be used to parse integers (no floating points). In your case it will only return 554. Additionally, calling parseInt() on a float will not round the number: it will take its floor (closest lower integer).

---

Extended example to answer Pedro Ferreira's question from the comments:

If the textfield contains thousands separator dots like in `1.234.567,99` those could be eliminated beforehand with another `replace`:

```
var fValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("textfield").value.replace(/\./g,"").replace(",","."))
```

Comment: What about the "." thousands separator? Like 4.554,20 what would return...?

Answer (score 17):

If you extend String object like this..

```
String.prototype.float = function() { 
  return parseFloat(this.replace(',', '.')); 
}
```

.. you can run it like this

```
"554,20".float()
> 554.20
```

works with dot as well

```
"554.20".float()
> 554.20

typeof "554,20".float()
> "number"
```

Comment: Although usually it's considered bad form to modify the base object prototypes. What if another framework also tried to do that but the functionality differed?

Answer (score 3):

@GusDeCool or anyone else trying to replace more than one thousands separators, one way to do it is a regex global replace: `/foo/g`.  Just remember that `.` is a metacharacter, so you have to escape it or put it in brackets (`\.` or `[.]`).  Here's one option:

```
var str = '6.000.000';
str.replace(/[.]/g,",");
```

Comment: yea, a replace without a regex only replaces one occurrence of the character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function. It will replace the commas with ' ' and then it will parseFlaot the value and after that it will again adjust the commas in value.

```
function convertToFloat(val) {
        if (val != '') {
            if (val.indexOf(',') !== -1)
                val.replace(',', '');
            val = parseFloat(val);
            while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
                val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for a way to parse **float** from an arbitrary string,

it can be done like that:

```
function extractFloat(text) {
  const match = text.match(/\d+((\.|,)\d+)?/)
  return match && match[0]
}

extractFloat('some text with float 5.25') // 5.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
let str ="554,20";
let float = +str.replace(',','.');
let int = str.split(',').map(x=>+x);

console.log({float,int});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem except I did not know in advance what were the thousands separators and the decimal separator. I ended up writing a library to do this. If you are interested it here it is : https://github.com/GuillaumeLeclerc/number-parsing