# jQuery calculation NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I have a view that output decimal values that represent money data types on the database. To output I am using the following formatting code

```
string price = String.Format("{0:f}", (item.Price + item.VAT));
```

that produce a string like this

```
12,99 (with comma as the decimal separator)
```

I am now using this string to make some calculation on the client using jQuery

```
elmProductSelected.children("option").each(function(n) {
    var pIdx = $(this).attr("rel"); 
    var pObj = products.eq(pIdx);
    var pValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var valueArray = pValue.split('|');
    var prdId = valueArray[0];
    var pQty = valueArray[1];
    /* the value of pPrice is 12,99 after the following call */
    var pPrice =  $(pObj).attr(attrProductPrice);
    /* I get NaN here! */
    sTotal = sTotal + ((pPrice - 0) * (pQty - 0));
    cProductCount++;
    cItemCount = cItemCount + (pQty-0);
});
```

I am getting **NaN** right on the line I have commented. I suppose that this is due to the fact that the `pPrice` value use the comma as the decimal separator because if I manually set it as `12.99` everything works.

Is there a way to read the `12,99` as a number using javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NaN = Not a number

By using `parseInt` you can tell Javascript that it should be treated as a number.

```
var pPrice = parseInt($(pObj).attr(attrProductPrice));
```

You might need `parseFloat` if you're using a decimal.

Comment: Both `parseInt` and `parseFloat` will cause you to lose the decimal places because of the `,`. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/E3DRd/) You'll need to manage the comma first.

Comment: You should always use the radix parameter with parseInt. parseInt('0012') -> 10, parseInt('0012', 10) -> 12.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with the code. First, you should cast the string to float, as Webnet suggests. The parseFloat function, however, will expect the argument to use dot as a decimal separator. Therefore, the following code will do what you want:

```
var pPrice = $(pObj).attr(attrProductPrice);
pPrice = parseFloat(pPrice.replace(',', '.'));
```

First, you replace the comma for a dot, then convert the result to a float.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only comma separator there will be (none for a thousands separator), then just replace it.

```
var num = parseInt( str.replace( ',', '.' ) ); // or parseFloat
```

If there are other characters that will prevent correct parsing, then I'd suggest having a custom attribute that stores the undecorated number.

```
<input data-undecorated="123.45" value="123,45" />
```

```
var num = parseInt( $('#myInput').data('undecorated') ); // or parseFloat
```

You can use `data()` like this to get `data-` attributes if you're using `jQuery 1.4.3` or later.

Comment: I think it should be parseFloat instead of parseInt

Comment: @Rafael: Very likely. I have it noted in the code comment. That wasn't the main point of the answer, but worth noting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegEx:

Update: Changed the expression, since I missed the part(with comma as the decimal separator).

```
var pPrice = $(pObj).attr(attrProductPrice)..replace(/(,)(\d+)$/, ".$2").replace(",","")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var pPrice = $(pObj).attr(attrProductPrice).split(",").join(".");
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks related: [How to convert string into float in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642650/how-to-convert-string-into-float-in-javascript)

It looks like you'll have to replace the comma with a decimal.

parseFloat('12,99'.replace(',', '.'))