# Javascript Nan Error: parsing strings to ints

Tags: javascript, parsing

References

[How to convert string into float in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642650/how-to-convert-string-into-float-in-javascript?rq=1)
[jQuery calculation NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542012/jquery-calculation-nan?lq=1)

Goal

Take two numerical input values from the user.
Divide the second number by the first number.
Multiply the result by 100 so it is represented as a percentage.
Add each number and the result to individual lists.
Call the function getTextInput() via onClick command.

Background

I primarily work with Java; I am currently in a data structures class (second year CS student). My proficiency is intermediate. My familiarity with javascript is basic.

Problem

NaN results. I have tried multiple methods to achieve this task; I parsed both input values and assigned them to new variables, and I parsed both initial string inputs to a float value. However, I am still having a problem parsing the result of these two numbers of type int or string to a float value. Should I be parsing to a float value of parameters of type int? When I convert the string values to int values the program won’t accept the input values and crashes. Why is this happening? I have looked at several related posts, but cannot find anything that provides the information I am looking for. What is the best method to go about this? Any help or direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

- NOTE Entire code posted at the very bottom.

  Method 1 - parsed two strings to float. ‘NaN’ result when I printed percentOfNumbers and percentageList to the console.

  var num1 = document.getElementById("numString1"); 
  var num2 = document.getElementById("numString2");

  percentOfNumbers = parseFloat(num2/num1 * 100); percentageList.push(percentOfNumbers); 
  percentOfNumbers.value = "";

  // add num1 to List1 
  List1.push(num1.value); 
  num1.value = "";

  // add num2 to List2 
  List2.push(num2.value); 
  num2.value= "";

  Method 2 - parsed each text input to an int value, parsed the result to a float value. ‘NaN’ result when I printed percentOfNumbers and percentageList to the console.

  var num1 = document.getElementById("numString1"); 
  var num2 = document.getElementById("numString2");

  var num1Parsed = parseInt(num1);
  var num2Parsed = parseInt(num2);

  percentOfNumbers = parseFloat(num2Parsed/num1Parsed * 100); percentageList.push(percentOfNumbers); 
  percentOfNumbers.value = "";

  // add num1 to List1 
  List1.push(num1Parsed.value); 
  num1Parsed.value = "";

  // add num2 to List2 
  List2.push(num2Parsed.value); 
  num2Parsed.value= "";

// EXAMPLE INPUT VALUES, 2000 for num1, 2233 for num2

// Entire Code

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
--><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script>

            // separate lists for repeat user input values for num1, num2, and percentageOfNumbers
            var List1 = [];
            var List2 = [];
            var percentageList = [];
            var percentOfNumbers = 0;
            var num1Parsed = 0;
            var num2Parsed = 0;

           function getTextInput() {

                // retrieve two numbers of type 'String' from user and assign to appropriate var
                var num1 = document.getElementById("numString1");
                var num2 = document.getElementById("numString2");

                // parse each string input number into an int
                num1Parsed = parseInt(num1);
                num2Parsed = parseInt(num2);

                // divide second number by first number
                // parse result and assign to percentOfNumbers var
                // add percentOfNumbers value to percentageList
                // reassign percentOfNumbers to ""
                percentOfNumbers = (num2Parsed/num1Parsed * 100);
                percentageList.push(percentOfNumbers);
                percentOfNumbers.value = "";

                // add num1 to List1
                List1.push(num1Parsed.value);
                num1Parsed.value = "";

                // add num2 to List2
                List2.push(num2Parsed.value); 
                num2Parsed.value= "";



           }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="numString1" type="text" name="input1" value="" /> 
        <input id="numString2" type="text" name="input2" value="" /> 
        <input id="inputField" type="button" name="search" value="compute" onClick="getTextInput();" /> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `num1` and `num2` variables doesn't contain strings, they contain the DOM elements.

Use the `value` property to get the value from the input fields:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("numString1").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("numString2").value;
```

Numbers however doesn't have a `value` property. You want to push the number itself:

```
List1.push(num1Parsed);
List2.push(num2Parsed);
```

Side note: Specify the base when you use `parseInt`, as numbers with leading zeroes are parsed using base 8 instead of 10:

```
num1Parsed = parseInt(num1, 10);
num2Parsed = parseInt(num2, 10);
```

Comment: Regarding *parseInt* and leading zeros, in [ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) the "specification of the function parseInt no longer allows implementations to treat Strings beginning with a 0 character as octal values". However, implementation still do. Go figure.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. That makes sense though. I have only recently begun to learn javascript, I appreciate your patience and help. The code is working.