# Bug with sum using comma separated numbers

Tags: jquery

I want to improve this code http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/30/ to use comma separated price in place of the point

as you we can seem when we use for example 1 x 375,5 I get 375 in the Sum and not 375,5

My code:

```
function ca(){
    var $overall = 0;

    $("tr.sum").each(function() {

        var $qnt = $(this).find(".qty");
        var $price = $(this).find("td").eq(1);

        console.log($qnt + " | " + $price);

        var sum = parseFloat($price.text()) * parseFloat($qnt.val());

        if(isNaN(sum)) {
            sum = 0;
        }
        $(this).find("td").eq(2).text(Math.round(sum * 100) / 100);

        $overall += sum;

    });

    $("#total").text($overall);
}

$(function() {

    ca();
    $('input.qty').bind('change keyup',function(){ca();});

});
```

Comment: Change the comma to a decimal point and it will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `,` to `.` before parsing the price and use `.toFixed(2)` to force 2 decimals at the results.

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/QmTNZ/38/

Answer (score 1):

`.replace("," , ".")`

http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/32/

more to read:

[How to convert string into float in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642650/how-to-convert-string-into-float-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, It works but I have to use always 2 numbers after the comma !

Comment: jsFiddle might be down some day, please add the relevant code to the answer.

Comment: I just wait for Bizboss to confirm the answer as correct, still don't know what he needs...

Comment: @Marek Sebera, Thanks
All the prices and The sum have always to use 2 numbers after the comma, not 3 and not 1 !

Answer (score 0):

In your html use are using both "," and "."

JavaScript uses "." for float numbers. "," is used for enumeration. Better change the prices to xx.yy rather than xx,yy .

For example this won`t work

```
var a = 12,1;
var b = 12.4, c = 0;
c = a + b;
```

You may also change this line ( objects tends to be integer in most of the cases :) )

```
var sum = parseFloat($price.text()) * parseFloat($qnt.val());
```

to

```
var sum = parseFloat($price.text()) * parseFloat( parseInt ($qnt.val() ) );
```