# Javascript function trouble

Tags: javascript, function

I'm having so much trouble with javascript. I'm supposed to make a simple paycheck program using function. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I also have to change the `payrate` and `taxrate` to a decimal format. How do you put that in code? Here's what my code looks like.

```
<html>
  <body bgcolor="#81DAF5">
  <head>
    <title>Chapter 4 Assignment 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var hoursworked = window.prompt("How many hours worked?", "");
      var payrate = window.prompt("What is the pay rate?", "");
      var taxrate = window.prompt("What is the tax rate?", "");
      var netpay
      parseFloat(payrate).toFixed(2);
      parseFloat(taxrate).toFixed(2);
      function calculatepay()
      {
        var grosspay= hoursworked * payrate;
        var taxamount= (grosspay * taxrate) / 100;
        var netpay= grosspay - taxamount;
        return netpay;
      }

      document.write("<h1><b>Hours Worked: " +hoursworked+ "<br></h1></b>");
      document.write("<h1><b>Hourly payrate: " +payrate+ "<br></h1></b>");
      document.write("<h1><b>Tax rate applied: " +taxrate+ "<br></h1></b>");
      document.write("<h1><b>Net Pay = " +calculatepay+ "<br></h1></b>");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are `hoursworked`, `payrate` and `taxrate` defined? What are you doing with the return value?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: The program starts with asking a prompt to the user. Saying "How many hours worked, How much is your pay rate, and What is the tax rate?"

Comment: OK, but what is "not working"?

Comment: at the end netpay says undefined

Comment: `parseFloat` does not transform the input, merely returns the transformed result.

Comment: Please make the title less vague. As written is will not be useful to future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems in the code

1. After parsing the input string, you need to assign the returned value back to the variable ex `payrate = parseFloat(payrate).toFixed(2);`
2. You need to invoke the function `calculatepay` by adding `()` at the end to print the result

Try

```
  var hoursworked = window.prompt("How many hours worked?", "");
  var payrate = window.prompt("What is the pay rate?", "");
  var taxrate = window.prompt("What is the tax rate?", "");
  payrate = parseFloat(payrate).toFixed(2);
  taxrate = parseFloat(taxrate).toFixed(2);
  function calculatepay()
  {
    var grosspay= hoursworked * payrate;
    var taxamount= (grosspay * taxrate) / 100;
    var netpay= grosspay - taxamount;
    return netpay;
  }

  var netpay = calculatepay();

  document.write("<h1><b>Hours Worked: " +hoursworked+ "<br></h1></b>");
  document.write("<h1><b>Hourly payrate: " +payrate+ "<br></h1></b>");
  document.write("<h1><b>Tax rate applied: " +taxrate+ "<br></h1></b>");
  document.write("<h1><b>Net Pay = " +netpay+ "<br></h1></b>");
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q2Vbd6OhjUJieR2qeyri?p=preview)

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I see it now. At the end I used netpay instead of the calculatepay().

Comment: @jaramore see the update, in that case you need to assign the calculated value the variable `netpay`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. While `parseFloat(payrate).toFixed(2)` does indeed seem to convert the stored value into a float, it stores the answer [as a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) instead.

Also, you should probably assign the result to another variable or back into `payrate` in any case, or the float/string will be lost.

Try:

```
payrate = parseFloat(payrate).toFixed(2);
taxrate = parseFloat(taxrate).toFixed(2);
```

and then in your `calculatepay()` function:

```
// neat trick at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5661399/1091386
// allows you to use a string as a float in addition/subtraction
// apparently not necessary with multiplication but I thought I'd leave it in

var taxamount = hoursworked * +(payrate);
```

and finally, don't forget to call `calculatepay()` at the end with the `()` or you will just return the function.

Answer (score 0):

When u use 
parseFloat(payrate).toFixedString(2);
The actual value is not changed.

Comment: What's the code to change them to decimal format? How do I fix the function, so netpay won't be undefined at the output.

Comment: Simply restore them to their own variables like:
Payrate=parseFloat(payrate).toFixedString(2)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your script a bit for you. A few small errors. You didnt include bracets when calling your calculate pay function, and you didnt store the result of applying the parseFloat method either.

applying the brackets gives:

```
document.write("<p>Net Pay = " + calculatepay() + "</p>");
```

storing the value:

```
payrate = parseFloat(payrate).toFixed(2);
taxrate = parseFloat(taxrate).toFixed(2);
```

also you dont need to declare each variable individually, you can do them all as a group by simply separating them with a comma:

```
var hoursworked = window.prompt("How many hours worked?", ""),
    payrate = window.prompt("What is the pay rate?", ""),
    payrate = parseFloat(payrate).toFixed(2),
    taxrate = window.prompt("What is the tax rate?", ""),
    taxrate = parseFloat(taxrate).toFixed(2),
    netpay = 0;
```

here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/2UVyH/2

hope that helps