# Convert negative number in string to negative decimal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string : `"-10.456"`
I want to convert it to `-10.465` in decimal (using JavaScript) so that I can compare for greater than or lesser than with another decimal number.

Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: Related: [How to convert string into float in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/642650/218196)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function can be used to parse strings to integers and uses this format: `parseInt(string, radix);`

Ex: `parseInt("-10.465", 10);` returns `-10`

To parse floating point numbers, you use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), formatted like `parseFloat(string)`

Ex: `parseFloat("-10.465");` returns `-10.465`

Comment: @Grice what if I am trying to add two decimal the trailing zeros are missing! 

+(parseFloat(3.6 + 4.4).toFixed(1))

if I use .toFixed it returns string and parseFloat return number but without decimal point/trailing zero

Answer (score 4):

Simply pass it to the [**`Number`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function:

```
var num = Number(str);
```

Comment: Number function only works if the number does not have any other, not a number string. if you have a '-10%' Number resolve NA

Answer (score 2):

Here are two simple ways to do this if the variable str = "-10.123":

### #1

str = str*1;

### #2

str = Number(str);

Both ways now contain a JavaScript number primitive now.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can compare mixed types.  So, this works:

```
var x = "-10.456";
var y = 5.5;
alert(x < y) // true
alert(x > y) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

the shortcut is this:

```
"-3.30" <--- the number in string form
+"-3.30" <----Add plus sign
-3.3 <----- Number in number type.
```

Comment: It keeps the decimal fraction and the sign, and it appears to be the fastest in Chrome: http://jsperf.com/number-vs-plus-vs-toint-vs-tofloat/14 (note: some of the tests convert to int!). You can also use a minus instead of a plus to negate the number. It even supports e-notation! (`+"12.34e5"`) I don't understand why no one upvoted this. Are there portability issues?