# Calculate (add up) with dot / comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add +20,2 to this sum with dot 9990.95 or this sum with comma 9990,95 with js or jquery

```
<span class="sum">9990.95</span>

var price = $( '.sum' ).text(),
    calc  = parseInt( price, 10 ) + 20,
    total = calc.toFixed( 2 );
```

Return me `9990` without decimal

I tried like this too

```
var price = $( '.sum' ).text(),
    calc  = 20,
    total = price + calc;
```

The output was `9990.9920`, which is not correct either.

Is there a way how to do that?

Comment: How do you know it returns `9990`? And you are looking for the `parseFloat` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string into float in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642650/how-to-convert-string-into-float-in-javascript) Please, search next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt` does exactly, what the label says -- parsing a string to an integer. Integers do not have decimals by definition.

Instead, [use `parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
calc = parseFloat(price) + 20,
```

Comment: Or just `calc  = +price + 20`.

Answer (score 2):

I think OP is looking for a way to parse numbers with point or comma as decimal separator into a floating point `Number`:

```js
let parseDecimalPoint = Number.parseFloat;
    parseDecimalComma = str => Number.parseFloat(str.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))

console.log(parseDecimalComma("+20,2") + parseDecimalComma("9990,95"));
console.log(parseDecimalComma("+20,2") + parseDecimalPoint("9990.95"));
```

See also [Javascript parse float is ignoring the decimals after my comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma)