# How to get number values from inputs?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to recreate the "check if hit" sistem from D&D in a small aplication and I need to get numeric values vrom input fields. Problem is, the normal document.queryselector('.input-class').value, only returns streengs. Any sugestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string into float in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642650/how-to-convert-string-into-float-in-javascript)

Comment: `parseInt(val)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can cast the string with **parseInt()**:

```js
let text = '42px';
let my_number = parseInt(text, 10);
// returns 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Add + before value to convert to the number.
Like:

```
let item = '2019';
assert(+item).toEqual(2019);
```

If you need some check, function isNaN() can be used after converting to number:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp