# How can I take in a string and parse it into a float?

Tags: javascript, integer-arithmetic

`preserveDecimal(n)` preserves `n`'s decimals (it parses `n` as a floating point number) and returns the parsed number:

> Error: Expected '2.222' to be 2.222

I am new to coding and I have been stuck on this assignment for a while.

Comment: parseFloat("2.222")... ?

Comment: `Number('2.222')`?

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642650/how-to-convert-string-into-float-in-javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string into float in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642650/how-to-convert-string-into-float-in-javascript)

Comment: I get an error saying that preserveDecimal(n) is not defined. I believe I have to declare it with a function and then return it but im not sure how to set up the code

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuilt function to pass your string to a float. It will be parsed if the string is a valid float.

let x = parseFloat(string)

Refer https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp for more information